# Is there a way to find the closest row match based on a different row match?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup-tables

I'm working with a data in which there are multiple sets of information in the same column. This is making it difficult to pick out the data I need as it always returns the first result. I am trying to find a way to ensure that the column result returned in a search is based on a different column's value. For example:

| Name/Date | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 | 04/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1 | 7 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| Jane | 1 | 7 | 9 | 3 | 1 |
| Jimmy | 8 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| Robin | 1 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 2 |
| Batman | 4 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 8 |
|  | 06/01/2022 | 07/01/2022 | 08/01/2022 | 09/01/2022 | 10/01/2022 |
| Bob | 4 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 12 |
| Jane | 6 | 21 | 9 | 3 | 1 |
| Jimmy | 8 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| Robin | 8 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 2 |
| Batman | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 8 |

If I wanted to yield the number for Jane on 07/01/2022 (which is `21`), is there any way of returning this? I've been able to use `=MATCH` to pull the correct column based on the date search criteria, but I cannot see a viable way of pulling for a particular person when their name appears multiple times in the same column. Attempting a lookup will return the first result for the name hit (so in the case of my Jane example, it would return row 3 instead of 9). I'm looking to be able to enter a name and a date, and it returns the result from that part of the array.

Is such a thing possible, please? If not, is there any workaround that may help to provide me the same result?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

- This is being attempting in Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- ms365 (specifically access to the BETA-channel);
- Equal intervals with the same names at the same postions;

[image]

Formula in `I4`:

```
=LET(X,WRAPCOLS(TOCOL(B1:F12,,1),6),SUM((A1:A6=I3)*FILTER(X,TAKE(X,1)=I2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in row 1
A1:F12 - data range
B17 - Jane
B18 - 07/01/2022

```
=LET(data,A1:F12,names,A1:A12,lookupname,B17,lookupdate,B18,INDEX(data,MIN(LET(rowlist,IF(names=lookupname,ROW(names),0),IF(rowlist>MAX(IF(data=lookupdate,ROW(data),0)),rowlist,""))),MAX(IF(data=lookupdate,COLUMN(data),0))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't quite get it working, it appears to return the wrong results. For example, I searched "Bob" and "05/01/2022" which should return 1, but instead it returns the value for 10/01/2022 of 12. Screenshot attached: https://i.imgur.com/GGuVvHn.png

Any assistance in figuring out what is causing this would be appreciated. Additionally (as I like to try and understand how things work so I'm not reliant on SO in the future, haha), what would happen, theoretically, if the data range didn't start on row 1 / column 1? Thanks so much!

Comment: OK, I see your screenshot now. Let me see.

Comment: Just edited to add the screenshot, which shows the data starting in row 1.

Comment: Just made an update to my original answer. Try the formula now.

Comment: this formula returns Excel row and column numbers found, so if wasn't starting in the first row you would need to subtract column and rows before to get to the right spot in index grid.